# Different style sheets for different divs

Tags: html, css

I have a page with 3 major divs. I want to have different link styles (all 4 link styles: link visited hover active) for each of them. As in, the links in div1 should be different from links in div2 and div3.

I know it is possible with some javascript (by putting class changers for mouse events) but I want to avoid js as much as possible. Is there any way I can achieve the same thing with css only?

Comment: That's so basic, it's impossible you couldn't find a solution alone

Comment: I know a solution exists for it, but I am not very well versed in css and I have forgotten where I read that on the internet.

Comment: Honestly, I'd suggest spending some time here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp at least until you get a better grasp on CSS. Click around the links on the left side, especially the one called CSS Selectors.

Comment: w3schools is my first search destination when I come across a stump in anything. I only didn't know what phrases to search for. I now got to learn that the idea at work here is called ***selector*** Not knowing the name of what you are looking for, is sometimes the biggest hurdle between you and something which the internet is filled to the brim with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `id` to each `div`

```
<div id="one">
    <a></a>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <a></a>
</div>
<div id="three">
    <a></a>
</div>
```

Then select those links like this

```
#one a {}
#two a {}
#three a {}
```

Comment: Many thanks. It worked. It would have been so much better if the commentators would have invested the same energy in posting an answer, instead of bashing me on my very basic question :)

Comment: Yes we are all here to learn, no matter the skill level. Knowing when to use ID attributes and how to use selectors is very important

Answer (score 0):

Use unique `id` to target div

```
<div id='div1'></div>
<div id='div2'></div>
<div id='div3'></div>


#div1{

}
#div2{

}
#div3{

}
```

And yes people are right this is a very basic question. You should google thing first try it out then if you encounter problems than you should ask questions here with problems.

Using separate style sheet will create multiple request to your server. You should try to minimize that.

Here you can learn more about [CSS SELECTORS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)